# Is there a plugin for keeping desktop icons same size and ordered?

Tags: 14.04, icons

I would like to have all icons in the same size, and in a ruled desktop. Currently if I try to order my Desktop Icons they can be stacked on top of another, and I hate that, because if I try to place an icon in the middle of other 2, it gets, literally, in the middle, not replacing the bottom one and making it move one place like in Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, which I partially resolve by right ckicking and unchecking the keep aligned choice, arranging the icons close to where I want them to be, then checking the keep aligned choice again and seeing if it got them right.  The icons are inclined to get mispositioned when keep aligned is rechecked, so you may have to repeat this several times.

Unfortunately, the icons sre likely to get scattered about the next time you log in, so I am afraid that this mismanagement looks like a bug in 14.04.